# Hiding radio button name/label along with button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to hide a radio button when another button is selected. I managed to hide the actual button but I can't find a way to hide the label/ name. This code below only hides the button.

```
document.getElementById('lights').style.display = 'none';
```

Code below is the actual button. I even trid putting the name in label tags.

```
Lights
<input  type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="lights" />
```

Comment: Well if you put it inside a label with an ID, then you can hide the label with a similar command at the same time. Or put all of it inside a span and hide the span. etc. etc. There are multiple ways you could achieve it.

Comment: Just now I tried putting it all in a div with an id and it worked. But are there other ways to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the "lights" word inside a label or a span then use "previousElementSibling" to hide it.

```js
const radioBtn = document.getElementById('lights');
radioBtn.style.display = 'none';
radioBtn.previousElementSibling.style.display = 'none';
```

```html
<span>Lights</span>
<input  type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="lights" />
```

Answer (score 0):

A better usability pattern would deemphasize it visually. Listen for clicks to the parent element and set a CSS class. Target the radio group's :checked attribute. Apply a style to the + next element, a label with a for= attribute.

```js
let selector = "fieldset";
let parent = document.querySelector(selector);
parent.onclick = function(event) {
  let element = event.target;
  // if click child, deemphasize
  if (element.nodeName.toLowerCase() != selector) {
    element.closest(selector).classList.add("taint");
  }
}
```

```css
.taint {
  border: 0.125em dotted red;
}

.taint input[type=radio]:not(:checked)+label {
  opacity: 0.25;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <input type="radio" name="hue" id="light" /><label for="light">Light</label>
  <input type="radio" name="hue" id="dark" /><label for="dark">Dark</label>
</fieldset>
```